# version of Nakayama's lemma for group rings

Tags: commutative-algebra, modules, representation-theory

I have the following rather complicated setting and I would like to know if something that resembles Nakayama's lemma can be proved in this setting, but I can make no progress with it:

Let $G$ be a finite group and let $K$ be a field of characteristic $0$. Assume that $M$ is a module over the polynomial ring $K[X]$, that $M$ is finitely generated as a $K$-module and also that there exists an action of the group $G$ on $M$, so that $M$ becomes a module the group ring $(K[X])[G]$.

I know in addition that the annihilator of $M$ in $K[X]$ is of the form $(X-c)^d$ for some $c \in K$, $d>0$ and that the set of elements in $M$ annihilated by $(X-c)$ is a cyclic $K[G]$-module (also the action of $X$ and $G$ commute). Does it follow that $M$ is cyclic as a $(K[X])[G]$-module?

Comment: So $M$ is not just a $K\left[X\right]$-module, but actually a $K\left[X\right] / \left(X-c\right)^d$-module. Note that $K\left[X\right] / \left(X-c\right)^d$ is a local ring, with its maximal ideal generated by $X-c$. This may help in applying regular Nakayama.

Comment: Is the set of elements in $M$ annihilated by $\left(X-c\right)$ isomorphic (as a $K\left[X\right]\left[G\right]$-module) to $M / \left(X-c\right)M$ ? Or, at least, is there a surjective $K\left[X\right]\left[G\right]$-module homomorphism frm the former to the latter? I suspect so; this would reduce your question to the standard Nakayama lemma.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I can see the obvious isomorphism $M/N \cong (X-c)M$ (where $N$ is the set of elements annihilated by $X-c$), but I don't see how to construct the 'swapped' version $M/(X-c)M \cong N$ you suggest

Comment: OK, I see why $M / \left(X-c\right) M \cong N$ **as $K\left[X\right]$-modules**: Both sides are $K\left[X\right] / \left(X-c\right)$-modules, which is the same as $K$-vector spaces, so it suffices to prove that their dimensions are equal; but this follows from looking at the Jordan normal form of a nilpotent endomorphism (the endomorphism being the action of $X-c$ on $M$). But this isomorphism is not canonical, so it is not clear at all that it will play well with the action of $G$.

Comment: For future discussions, let's agree to simplify our life and substitute $Y$ for $X-c$.

Comment: @darijgrinberg I understand the argument for $M/YM \cong N$. I have also been trying several ideas in the meantime, such as proving recursively that for all $j$ the submodule of $M$ annihilated by $Y^j$ must be $(K[X])[G]$-cyclic, but did not get very far with it.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe there's a more elegant way to prove this, but one way to do it is to just classify all such modules.  First, we may assume $c=0$.  By Artin-Wedderburn, $K[G]$ is isomorphic to a product $\prod M_{n_i}(D_i)$ of matrix rings over division rings, and then $K[G][X]\cong \prod M_{n_i}(D_i[X])$.   Any $K[G][X]$-module $M$ then splits as a product $\prod M_i$ of modules over each $M_{n_i}(D_i[X])$, and $M$ is cyclic iff each $M_i$ is cyclic.

So, it suffices to prove the following.  Suppose $D$ is a division ring and $M$ is a finitely generated $M_n(D[X])$-module that is annihilated by some power of $X$ such $N=\{a\in M:Xa=0\}$ is a cyclic $M_n(D)$-module.  Then $M$ is cyclic.

To prove this, note first that any finitely generated $D[X]$-module which is annihilated by some power of $X$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of modules of the form $D[X]/(X^i)$.  (There several ways to prove this; some commonly used proofs of this fact over fields (which amounts to Jordan normal form for nilpotent matrices) work just as well over division rings.  Another approach is to show that $D[X]/(X^i)$ is injective as a module over itself using Baer's criterion (the only ideals in $D[X]/(X^i)$ are those generated by powers of $X$) and then use this to repeatedly peel of direct summands of the form $D[X]/(X^i)$ where $i$ is minimal such that $X^i$ annihilates the module.)  By the Morita equivalence of $D[X]$ and $M_n(D[X])$, similarly any finitely generated $M_n(D(X))$-module which is annihilated by some power of $X$ is a direct sum of modules of the form $D^n\otimes_D D[X]/(X^i)$.

So, $M$ is a direct sum of modules of the form $D^n\otimes_D D[X]/(X^i)$, and then $N$ will be a direct sum of copies of $D^n$, one for each summand in $M$.  An $M_n(D)$-module is cyclic iff it is a direct sum of at most $n$ copies of $D^n$, so if $N$ is cyclic, there are at most $n$ summands in $M$.  But then $M$ is a quotient of a direct sum of at most $n$ copies of $D^n\otimes_D D[X]$, and so $M$ is a cyclic $M_n(D[X])$-module.